# В react обратиться к nth-child

Tags: css, reactjs

Есть простой итерируемый компонент:

```
<MainComponent>
  {data.map((price}) => (
  <div>{price}</div>
))}
</MainComponent>
```

Дивов может быть несколько. Как мне в стилях обратиться к одному из них, например, к третьему?
Для стилизации используется emotion.

Comment: Все действо в Реакт должно идти "от стейта". Т.е. элемент должен отрисовываться "опираясь" на некий стейт или пропсы. В методе `map` можно получить порядковый номер элемента, сравнить его с неким значением и применить стили, если это нужно.

Comment: Если это просто такая стилизация списка - css будет работать так же, можно использовать `<родитель> :nth-child(3);`